# Call string constructor function

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor function, for example webapp.core.cf1 or Backbone.Router. But I get this constructor function not as a reference, but as a string! I cannot change this requirement, the constr. must be in a string. How can I make a new object from this, for instance classfun("Backbone.Router")?

```
function classfun (cfstr) 
{ 
  ...
  cf = new window[cfstr]();
```

If I try it this way, I get the error: ... is not a constructor.

Why this does not work? Is there an alternative way without using `eval()`?

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT

Thank you all for your answers!

Thank you, Tronix117, this was the problem!!

Thank you, Benjamin Schulte, for the function!

Comment: Can you give a complete example? Perhaps, on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: and also, sample code of what you really want to happen?

Comment: How do you call `classfun`? What type of variable are you passing into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try in your console:

```
var A=function(a){this.test=a};
b = new window["A"](3);
console.log(b.test); // return 3
```

So that means, you are trying to access something which is not in the scope of window, it should rather be something like that: window.something["A"], if you don't know what is `something` then you should use the function of Benjamin, otherwise use this one, because it's way faster.

Comment: Good stuff checking the `window` object for the property of the classname. This solved an issue I was having. Thanks!

Comment: Not that his question asked this, but what about in non-browser js?

Comment: @catbadger there is always a top level object, it's usualy `global` in non-browsers environments like node.js and `window` in browser environments. If you want to be cross-env (brower + non browser), you can do this: `typeof global === 'undefined' && (window.global = window)`  at the beginning of the script, and use `global` everywhere you need. So in the above exemple you then do `b= new global['a'](3)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way (if I understand you correctly):

```
function getObjectByName(name) {
    var nameParts = name.split('.');
    var nameLength = nameParts.length;
    var scope = window;

    for (var i=0; i<nameLength; ++i) {
        scope = scope[nameParts[i]];
    }

    return scope;
}

var ObjectClass = getObjectByName(cfstr)
new ObjectClass();
```

Can still be optimized, but should work this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReflectUtil.newInstance = function(strClass) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var clsClass = eval(strClass);
    function F() {
        return clsClass.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = clsClass.prototype;
    return new F();
};

SomeClass = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
}

ReflectUtil.newInstance('SomeClass', 5, 7);
```

This will allow you to instantiate an object by its name and allow you to pass parameters as necessary.